# Trigger function for table with multiple joins PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-function

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I didn't find any questions specifically for this issue.

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL trigger with a table which contains joins.

**Table A**

| Salesman_id | Salesman name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Snow |
| 2 | Jennifer |
| 3 | Cleiton |

**Table B**

| Salesman_id | order value | item | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | Bananas | 1 |
| 2 | 1000 | tomatos | 20 |
| 3 | 5000 | Tigers | 200 |

**Joined Table A-B** (Selected couple columns)

| Salesman name | Order Value |
| --- | --- |
| John Snow | 500 |
| Jennifer | 1000 |
| Cleiton | 5000 |

my code for this trigger:

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION atualiza_tabela()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
    if new.order_id<>old.order_id then

    INSERT INTO Table A-B (Salesman_id, Salesman name, order value, item, order id)
    VALUES (NEW.Salesman_id, NEW.Salesman name, NEW.order value, NEW.item, NEW.order id);

    RETURN NULL;

    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is there any syntax error or another kind of error in my code?

It returns:

```
  ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
  LINE 35: END;
            ^
  SQL state: 42601
  Character: 748
```

Comment: You are missing the `END IF;`. You should indent your code correctly, that will make errors like this one obvious.

Comment: No `END IF;` per [Conditionals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS). The docs are the best place to start for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, now it works. I will pay more attention to the indentation from now on!